# Rewrite rule using htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my application we have write root directory name(gaming) statically in coding on some pages which are showing as link in GUI. Now whenever I am trying to click on such URLs its redirect me on url1 which is not accessible for me. So is there any possible ways in which I can access url1 without remove such statically name throughout application?

URL 1 :

```
http://abc:8089/gaming/app/test/unique_testing.php
```

URL 2 :

```
http://abc:8089/app/test/unique_testing.php
```

I have tried some htaccess overwrite rules but it's not working for me.
My current htaccess looks like below :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^gaming(/.*|)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Structure :

```
  /var/www/html/gaming/app/test/unique_testing.php
  /var/www/html/gaming/.htaccess
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass just one param? e.g.,
http://abc:8089/app/

Comment: Sorry i can't get your point

Comment: you have pass there params e.g.
/gaming/app/test/ to the file

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I gave that's just one example actually application is too large so i can't write every module there else htaccess will become too large.
Is that not possible to write using single htaccess rule ?

Comment: leaving the gaming you want to pass remaining as url?

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Are you getting 404 for `http://abc:8089/gaming/app/test/unique_testing.php` ?

Comment: @anubhava htaccess is located at gaming/.htaccess

Comment: @Sasikumar yes, but for all pages not for any static pages.Because i have very large set so its not good for me so just want to know its possible or not

Comment: Which URL is working at present for you? `http://abc:8089/gaming/app/test/unique_testing.php` or `http://abc:8089/app/test/unique_testing.php`?

Comment: http://abc:8089/app/test/unique_testing.php? is working for me

Comment: Do u want both URLs to be accessible

Comment: Yes i need like that

Answer (score 0):

Inside root `/gaming./.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^app(?:/.*)?$ /$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But let me edit my question to give clear idea about question

Comment: Still not clear. If everything is inside `/gaming/` then how is `http://abc:8089/app/test/unique_testing.php` URL working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this rules in your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```